# delete an extra blank line with AppendLine?

Tags: c#

Hello I am making a report with word but at the moment of showing the records with AppendLine it generates a blank line too
How could I do so that the last record does not generate a blank line?

```
 if (lista.GetType().Equals(typeof(List<DetalleMapa3>)))
                    {
                        var lstTemp = lista as List<DetalleMapa3>;
                        foreach (var item in lstTemp)
                        {
                            sData.AppendLine(item.Concepto6);
                        }
                    }
```

As you can see in the image, the last record with check is blank
[image]

the white space is not a record of my query but is a line break
[image]

Comment: `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstTemp.Select(item => item.Concepto6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (lista.GetType().Equals(typeof(List<DetalleMapa3>)))
                {
                    var lstTemp = lista as List<DetalleMapa3>;
                    //foreach (var item in lstTemp)
                    for(int i=0;i<lstTemp.Count;i++)
                    {
                        if(i<lstTemp.Count-1)
                            sData.AppendLine(lstTemp[i].Concepto6);
                        else
                            sData.Append(lstTemp[i].Concepto6);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
var lstTemp = lista as List<DetalleMapa3>;
if (lstTemp != null)
{
    sData.Append(
        String.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            lstTemp.Select(x => x.Concepto6)));
}
```